# download with pip3 packages for another python release

Tags: download, pip, offline

I own an off grid server (linux x86_64 with python3.8) on which I would like to install pypi packages. Up to now, I download manually each package and dependencies from pypi.org. And it is painful.

I would like to use `pip3 download` feature which is perfect for my needs ! Except the platform I download from is very different (win_amd64 with python3.6). Since I want to get `numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`, I tried :

```
pip3 download --verbose --only-binary=:all: --abi=cp38 --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 numpy
```

And, checking the verbose log, for the line which correspond to the expected wheel, I get a `it is not compatible with this Python`... Of course it isn't !

How could I force pip3 to download the appropriate `.whl` file even if it is not the correct one for the platform I download it from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing `--abi`, you have to also pass the `--python-version` so `pip` can build the correct platform tag. This should work (untested):

```
$ pip3 download --only-binary=:all: --python-version=38 --abi=cp38 --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 numpy
```

Although admitted, `pip download` is anything but reliable, e.g. when it comes to resolving environment markers and stuff.

Comment: "*`pip download` is anything but reliable*" And it stuck on dependencies of source-only (non-wheel) packages.

Comment: @phd True, we have to maintain an extra index with prebuilt wheels just because of that.

Comment: nice ! thanks... I tried many combinations, but never reached the good one. As unreliable as pip download is, it is better than manually downloading deps. And when it will fails, I'll fallback to the old manual way :)